# global variable scope in javascript with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I have a node.js server with mysql plugin from flexiage:
Here goes my code:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM students WHERE email="'+req.body.username+'" AND password="'+req.body.password+'"',function(err,rows){


    if(rows.length)
    {

        var response=new Object;
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM forums WHERE id="'+rows[0].courseInterest+'"',function(err,course){

            response.subscription=course;
            response.username=rows[0].email;
            response.password=rows[0].password;
            response.loginFailed=false;
            response.loginAccepted=true;
        });

    }
    else
    {

        var response=new Object;
        response.username="";
        response.password="";
        response.loginFailed=true;
        response.loginAccepted=false;

    }
    console.log(response);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(response);

});
```

In console i just get a blank object. It does go in the if condition but unable to attach prpoerties inside the construct. My guess is the variable scope because if i do a console.log inside connection.query construct it returns the result as desired.
Please shed light.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196, it's basically the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no scope problem, because scopes aren't block based in JavaScript and your variable declarations are hoisted.

The response is empty because the `query` function is asynchronous and you log and send the response before mysql answered.

Answer the browser in the callback :

```
var response=new Object;
var sendResponse = function(){
    console.log(response);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(response);
}
connection.query('SELECT * FROM students WHERE email="'+req.body.username+'" AND password="'+req.body.password+'"',function(err,rows){
    if (rows.length) {
        response=new Object();
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM forums WHERE id="'+rows[0].courseInterest+'"',function(err,course){
            response.subscription=course;
            response.username=rows[0].email;
            response.password=rows[0].password;
            response.loginFailed=false;
            response.loginAccepted=true;
            sendResponse();
        })
    } else {
        response=new Object;
        response.username="";
        response.password="";
        response.loginFailed=true;
        response.loginAccepted=false;
        sendResponse();
    }
});
```